# "Index out of range" while reading contents from a file through cat PYTHON

Tags: python, shell, input, cat

I am trying to get input from a file, through cat command, into a python file. My python version is 3.5. The code looks like this.

```
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    while True:
        if f.readline()== '':
            break
        line = f.readline().strip()
```

And i am getting the input through the following command.

```
python cptest.py | cat ts.csv
```

But i keep running into the following error.

> File "cptest.py", line 9, in 
>       with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
>   IndexError: list index out of range

How can i send input to a python script from a file using cat command? I have to use cat command, or any other way i can pipe the input to the file.

Comment: A pipe is not passed in as a command line argument. You want to read from `sys.stdin()`, not try to open `sys.argv[1]`.

Comment: I think you wanted to do `python cptest.py ts.csv | cat`

Comment: @alec_djinn no actually it was `cat ts.csv | python cptest.py`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it is your command is the issue here. You are piping the output from your python script to cat and also use cat to open a file which means cat will ignore whatever you pipe to it. You should pipe the output of cat to your script instead: `cat ts.csv | python cptest.py`
Then, in order to read input from the standard input in python (from the pipe) you should do it like this: `for line in sys.stdin`.
I would lite to suggest the alternative of providing the filename to your python script as an argument like so: `python cptest.py ts.csv` and then open this file (you find this name in sys.argv[1] in python (and not with cat) and loop through it line by line.

Good luck,
Teo

Comment: Thank you, `cat ts.csv | python cptest.py` did the job. The command was indeed the error, and i needed to use `sys.stdin()` instead of `sys.argv[1]`